# laravel controller not returning data but the condition in the where clause is true?

Tags: laravel, where-clause, clause

I am using laravel 9x. I made the condition where(email,'Auth::user()->email)->where('active','!=',3)->get();

there is a lot of data where active is not equal to 3 but still, it's not returning any data.

Comment: and only one with the condition where(email,'Auth::user()->email)

Comment: I am not sure if this be the cause, but I see an extra ' in the condition before "Auth", where(email,'Auth::user()->email).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use not equal in the builder you should use '<>' instead of '!=';